# deploy asp.net core angular application to iis

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I created an ASP.NET Core Angular application
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYOGZ.png)

I'm trying to deploy it into my IIS but have some problems.
I uploaded it into my server but as you can see in the console log that if you go into the "fetch-data" tab [this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b521W.png).

In localhost all works perfect. After I did [publish to folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWp6B.png)
and uploaded it into my server the client side not able to access it via HTTP.

Here is the asp.net core controller function:

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            List<Country> countries;
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/all");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
                request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "a75567071fmsh1da754f34ee180dp16140cjsnd0ce561437aa");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(response.Content);

            }
            catch
            {
                string countriesJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\\tmp\\countries.json");
                countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(countriesJson);
            }


            foreach (Country c in countries)
            {
                dictionary.Add(c.alpha3Code, c.name);
            }
            


            return Enumerable.Range(0, countries.Count - 1).Select(index => new Country
            {
                name = countries[index].name,
                capital = countries[index].capital,
                languages = countries[index].languages,
                timezones = countries[index].timezones,
                borders = countries[index].borders.Select(s => dictionary[s]).ToList(),
                flag = "https://www.countryflags.io/" + countries[index].alpha2Code + "/flat/64.png",
                population = countries[index].population,
                nativeName = countries[index].nativeName,
                currencies = countries[index].currencies,
                region = countries[index].region,
            });
        }
```

and here is the HTTP get request from the angular component:

```
 http.get<Country[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Countries/GetCountries').subscribe(result => {
      this.countreis = result;
      this.filterCountries = this.countreis;

      this.config = {
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        totalItems: this.countreis.length
      };


    }, error => console.error(error));
```

Also here is the .angular-cli.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "Liveperson"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../liveperson/wwwroot",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "build": {
      "progress": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: also, I tried in angular-cli.json file that outDir parameter will be dist ("outDir": "dist") and got the same error.

Comment: your api is not accessible, network tab shows 404 error. Call is going to http://13.53.103.103/api/Countries/GetCountries , that isn't accessible

Comment: so how to make it accessible

Comment: Did you use URL rewrite? Can you post the directory structure of the project in IIS? This may also be because the project has not been successfully deployed to IIS. For how to host asp.net core in IIS, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1